Manual exception logging in datadog
Datadog appears to only log uncaught exceptions, but there are certain caught exceptions that I would like to log as exception as well. I've been trying to log them manually by adding them to a span, but they aren't showing up under datadog's error tracking tab. What am I doing incorrectly?
This is the function that I am using. I have stored the locals present at the time that the exception was raised within the exception itself.
def trace_exception(ex: BaseException, span):
    if span is None:
        return
    span.set_traceback()
    span.set_tag("error", True)
    span.set_tag("error.type", type(ex).__name__)
    span.set_tag("error.message", str(ex))
    span.set_tag("error.stack", "".join(traceback.format_tb(ex.__traceback__)))
    locals_dict = getattr(ex, "locals", {})
    for var_name, var_value in locals_dict.items():
        span.set_tag(f"local.{var_name}", str(var_value))

